# What's the best way to add static text to a Java Swing menu?

Tags: java, swing, menu, jlabel, jpopupmenu

I want to include some static text in a popup menu. I'd like it to look just like any other menu item, just not selectable. Ways I have tried:

- Add a disabled JMenuItem to the menu. While this results in the correct font and alignment, it causes the text to be rendered in light grey and be almost unreadable.
- Add a JLabel to the menu. This looks ugly; the label uses a different font than the regular menu items, and is not aligned the same (the menu items leave space for an icon to the left, the label does not do that).

  ```
  JPopupMenu popupMenu = new JPopupMenu();
  JLabel label = new Label("Static text);
  popupMenu.add(label);
  JMenuItem menuItem = new JMenuItem("Disabled menu item);
  menuItem.setEnabled(false);
  popupMenu.add(menuItem);
  menuItem = new JMenuItem("Regular item);
  popupMenu.add(menuItem);
  ```

Am I missing some other way to add static text to a menu which uses the same font and alignment as a regular menu item, but is unselectable, does not accept the keyboard focus and is not highlighted when the mouse hovers over it?

Comment: From a users perspective, this would be confusing/annoying if the text looks the same as other clickable options. If you're just trying to categorize menu options, maybe a submenu would be a better approach?

Comment: hmmm noting wrong with JLabel, I saw that a few times, looks good, put JSeparator under JLabel, and second to the bottom of JPopupMenu, use JLabel.setFont(myJMenuItem.getFont or get this value from UIManager for JMenuItem )

Comment: some LookAndFeels has implemented vertical lable for JPopuMenu, JMenu with JMenuItems

Comment: You can use, as well, a JXTitledSeparator from SwingX library. They have a demo so you can look whether it matches your needs: https://swingx.java.net/

Comment: Disable the JMenuItem and change the font color

Comment: Thanks for the comments everyone. Unfortunately they all result in one ugly difference or another (different alignment; a drop shadow behind the text, etc.). Note that I'm developing on Linux against the GTK look and feel; it may be look and feel dependent (I need something that works on all look and feels).  
I'll investigate the JXTitledSeparator, thanks for the tip Igor.

Answer (score 2):

Years too late for the OP, but a simple way of achieving the same thing without having to fiddle around with L&F guesswork is to remove the event listener that highlights the button when the mouse is passing over it.

```
JMenuItem menuItem = ......
if (menuItem.getModel() instanceof DefaultButtonModel) {
    DefaultButtonModel model = (DefaultButtonModel)menuItem.getModel();
    model.setArmed(false);
    for (ChangeListener cl : model.getChangeListeners()) {
        //System.err.format("yep, removing %s%n", cl);
        model.removeChangeListener(cl);
    }
}
menuItem.setFocusable(false);
menuItem.setForeground ....
menuItem.setBackground ....
menuItem.setFont ....
menuItem.setHorizontalAlignment ....
```

Note that this is somewhat extreme, in that if there were any *other* event listeners registered on the "button which is now a label", they'll be nuked as well, and there's no meaningful way to tell them apart.

You can also do a `JLabel`, but then of course you'll need to do a lot of the positioning and drawing that the `JMenuItem`/`AbstractButton` code and L&F would have done for you.

(And don't be misled by the "rollover" functionality in Swing; it would normally be exactly for this kind of thing, but is not used in menus and menu items.)

Comment: Actually, this is a great way to achieve the OP's goal.  I used this in my context, just by leaving out "addActionListener" on the menuItem in the first place.  I agree with other posters that this can be confusing to users if not used appropriately, since it looks exactly like the other menu items, but that's precisely what the OP asked for.

Answer (score 1):

The following works fine for me. Just add JLabel to JPanel and add JPanel to your JPopupMenu

```
JPanel panelLabel = new JPanel();       
JLabel lblSomeText = new JLabel("Some text");
lblSomeText.setFont(menuItem.getFont());
lblSomeText.setForeground(menuItem.getForeground());
panelLabel.add(lblSomeText);
popupMenu.add(panelLabel);
```

Comment: The problem is that the label is not aligned the same. The label is shown flush with the left side of the menu, while the menu items leave a little space to the left. Maybe this is dependent on the look and feel; I'm developing on Linux and using the default system look and feel (which is GTK).